# JTable using binding, how to get selected Element?

Tags: java, database, jpa, binding

I'm using binding machanism to show data from database table in jTable. I've had problem with adding new Element and refreshing jTable, but finally I solved it (observable property in List). Now I want to get Element from jTable, change it (setters) and save changes (flush?). How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved.

`Element elem = (Element) list.get(jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(jTable.getSelectedRow()));`

where:
`Element` - entity class
`list` - `entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Element e").getResultList();`

Make sure list is **observable** (to see changes in jTable immidiately).